# Talend - Send HTTP POST Request with form-data

Tags: api, rest, talend

I'm facing a weird issue here,
I'm trying to send this request with Talend

[image]

And I can't figure out how to use the Talend Rest components (tRest and tRestClient)

For the tRest :

[image]

I have a response but not the expected one (unfiltered data instead of a single profil base on the idAgent)

And for the tRestClient I tried this way :

[image]

[image]

and configured this way :

[image]

And I have the same response for tRestClient case

Is there something missing in the components configuration (type, ...) or am I doing this wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: You might need to define query parameters in the tRESTClient, i.e name=idAgent, value=row7.idAgent.

Comment: Hi @clanc9 thanks for the reply I tried your suggestion and it didn't work either so I try another approach I created a java routine that answers what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying multiple solutions, configurations, ... and nothing worked. So I created a routine that did what I needed using the java.net.HttpURLConnection library.

here is the routine :

```
public class plannetAPI {
private final String boundary;
private static final String LINE = "\r\n";
private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
private String charset;
private OutputStream outputStream;
private PrintWriter writer;





/**
 * plannetAPI: This constructor initializes a new HTTP POST request with content type
 * is set to multipart/form-data
 * 
 * {Category} User Defined
 *
 * @param rurl
 * @param token
 * @param charset
 * @throws MalformedURLException
 */
public plannetAPI(String rurl, String token, String charset) throws MalformedURLException {
    this.charset = charset;
    //HttpURLConnection httpConn;
    boundary = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    URL url = new URL(rurl);
    try {
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);    // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("token", token);
        outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset), true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    
    
}


/**
 * Adds a form field to the request
 *
 * @param name  field name
 * @param value field value
 */
public void addFormField(String name, String value) {
    writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE);
    writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"").append(LINE);
    writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(LINE);
    writer.append(LINE);
    writer.append(value).append(LINE);
    writer.flush();
}





/**
 * Completes the request and receives response from the server.
 *
 * @return String as response in case the server returned
 * status OK, otherwise an exception is thrown.
 * @throws IOException
 */
public String finish() throws IOException {
    String response = "";
    writer.flush();
    writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE);
    writer.close();

    // checks server's status code first
    int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
    if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = httpConn.getInputStream().read(buffer)) != -1) {
            result.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        response = result.toString(this.charset);
        httpConn.disconnect();
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
    }
    return response;
}
```

}

And then used it in a custom joblet :

[image]

And use the routines like this :

```
              try {

                routines.plannetAPI multipart = new routines.plannetAPI(((String)globalMap.get("URL")), ((String)globalMap.get("TOKEN")), "utf-8");
                // Add form field
                multipart.addFormField("idAgent", ((String)globalMap.get("IDAGENT")));
                String response = multipart.finish();
                System.out.println(response);
                row2.id_agent = response;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

But I would still like to know if there is a way of just doing this with Talend components and no having to work around with custom routines and joblets, ...

Thanks